# How to get all history of CLPPLUS SQL command?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, clpplus

I am using CLPPlus: Version 1.6 to connect my IBM Db2 on cloud.
I have written several sql queries back long ago.
And I am willing to refer my queries which I had fired that time.

So basically I want the history of my clpplus terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up & down arrow keys allow you to list command history.
You may save the results and history of commands with the `SET ECHO ON;` and `SPOOL full_path_to_logfile;` commands as well.

Comment: Thanks this is what I am looking for.